# Getting values from lookup in SQL

Tags: soql

I have the following situation

- Object **MortgageApplication**: has a lookup field called
  PrimaryLoanApplicant. The lookup is against Object **Loan
  Applicant**. The child relationship name is called LA
- Object Loan Applicant: Has a look up field called contactid. The
  lookup is against **Contact** object. The child relationship name is called CLA

I am trying to get the Applicants name from the Contact object along with some other fields/details from Mortgage Application object.

```
MortgageApplication ma = [SELECT Id, Name, Status, (SELECT contactid__r.name from la__r), Amount_of_Funding_Required__c
        FROM MortgageApplication
        WHERE Id =:sbaId]
```

When I write the following, I get 'Didn't understand relationship __r error'.

I am getting this terribly wrong. Can someone give me a tip on how to get this query working?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use child relationship query because your `LoanApplicant` object is a **parent** of `MortgageApplication` object. Simply use the dot notation.

For example:
If your lookup field to the LoanApplicant object is `La__c`:

```sql
MortgageApplication ma = [SELECT Id, Name, Status, la__r.contactid__r.name, Amount_of_Funding_Required__c
        FROM MortgageApplication
        WHERE Id =:sbaId]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I get it. It did resolve the issue. Big thanks.